# remove minutes portion from time when value zero angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, time

I am calling a API where I get the following json data

```
[{"id":"1","start_time":"07:30 AM","end_time":"11:00 AM","status":"1"},{"id":"2","start_time":"11:00 AM","end_time":"02:00 PM","status":"1"},{"id":"3","start_time":"02:00 PM","end_time":"05:00 PM","status":"1"},{"id":"4","start_time":"05:00 PM","end_time":"08:30 AM","status":"1"},{"id":"5","start_time":"09:00 PM","end_time":"11:00 PM","status":"1"},{"id":"6","start_time":"11:00 PM","end_time":"01:30 AM","status":"1"},{"id":"7","start_time":"01:30 AM","end_time":"07:30 AM","status":"1"}]
```

**start_time=07:30 AM**, that's fine.
But when I get **start_time = 11:00 AM (zero minute)** I want to show it as **start_time = 11 AM**.
[I have marked the zero minutes here in output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCO8G.jpg)

if minutes are greater than zero then show them
else hide them with the colon(:) sign.
**How can I do that?**

Comment: you can use the angular timer please see https://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/

Comment: Thank you @Swarnava Sarkar.. I will definitely use your codes. These are interesting. But the present problem is little bit complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    timeSlot=[];
    function reduceTime(st, et) {
        var obj={
            start_time:'',
            end_time:''
        };
        if (st.indexOf(":00")>0){
            obj.start_time=st.replace(":00", "")
        }else{
            obj.start_time=st;
        }
        if (et.indexOf(":00")>0){
            obj.end_time=et.replace(':00', '')
        }else{
            obj.end_time=et;
        }
        timeSlot.push(obj)
    }
```

usage:

```
for(i=0;i<response.length;i++){
                reduceTime(response[i].start_time, response[i].end_time)
            }
            $scope.timeSlot=timeSlot;
```

Then we will get an array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
function reduceTime(obj, prop) {
    var colon_index = obj.indexOf(':');
    if(obj[prop][colon_index + 1] == '0' && obj[prop][colon_index + 2] == '0') {
        return obj[prop].slice(0, colon_index + 1);
    }   
    return obj[prop];
}
```

Usage:

```
obj = reduceTime(obj, 'start_time');
```

Comment: When 1:00 AM or 2:00 PM upto 9:00 PM ?? that means First letter is single number

Comment: That's great. Thank you @Tarun Dugar.. I have edited a little.. you just saved my day :)

Comment: I think we should use replace() rather than slice(). Because am/pm also goes hidden if we use slice()..